# Reading AND Writing Access 2 with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I went for a job interview this morning, and one of the scenarios that the IT manager (a former programmer) told me about was the following .... If anyone could give me any pointers that I can email him pointers to tomorrow (Wednesday 22nd) it may just help tip his decision in my direction. So there's beer in it if you answer a relevent answer, and I get the job.

Old systems using Access 2 databases. These systems are not due to be updated any time soon.

New systems need access to that data, so each night he exports information using SSIS. However, he needs to also write data back, and more often than just overnight.

However, when he connects to the database, using ODBC connections I think, he says that the app (SSIS) opens the tables / database exclusively, even if he selects the option NOT to open it exclusively.

Any ideas, suggestions or comments ?

Comment: Migrate the data to sql server or mysql.

Comment: You will, of course, provide full attribution when you present the solution to your potential new employer, right? :-)

Comment: The answer is, upgrade the databases. Access 2 is from the '90s (assuming you mean MS Access).

Comment: Joe Stefanelli ... The will be told that I got the answers externally through my network of 'connections'. If I got the job I might point him to Stackoverflow, but passing the potential solution or ideas will be attributed as coming from 'externally'. After all, it's not important for employees to know the answer to everything, but to know where to go for answers.

Comment: @Doug ... the systems and data WILL be migrated to SQL Server and a .NET replacement application, but that the moment there is a requirement to share the data immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the  Access db itself is set up to open exclusively. Gosh it's been about a million years since I used Access 2.

Another possibility to fix is to consider making the SQl server tables that mimic the access tables and making them linked tables in access and using them instead of access. I can't remember if you can do this with Access 2 or not. If you can do this, then you will be making changes directly to the sql servver tables and not locking them up in Access 2. It's at least something to try. The use of linked tables should't break anything in Access if they have the same names and all tables havea primary key. ANd then you can performance tune as well if there are problems.

I'm throwing out ideas here, up to you to research the feasibilty before sending them on. But honestly, do you really really want to work for an organization that still uses Access2? If they haven't upgraded that, what else are they years out of date on? Access2 came out in 1993. So they haven't upgraded it in 17 years, scary stuff.

Comment: Yes I would consider working for this organisation because the guy is expanding the IT department in a small, privately-owned, and growing and profitable engineering company. Which is very rare in this country at the moment. Updating these old systems is on his schedule. Most places have 'legacy' systems somewhere, and at least this is so old, the case for replacing it is becoming easier for the directors to accept.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Oh, and they have lasers that cut stuff. Who WOULDN'T want to work for a firm like that ?